# Network error(ConnectionError) while using wandb

Tags: windows, machine-learning, pycharm, wandb

I've try to use wandb today and run the quickstart code locally in Pycharm,

though I can use `wandb login` command to log in but when I try to run the py file, the error:

```
C:\Users\34959\anaconda3\envs\ml\python.exe D:\ML_Projects\pythonProject\wand.py 
wandb: Network error (ConnectionError), entering retry loop.
wandb: W&B API key is configured. Use `wandb login --relogin` to force relogin
wandb: Network error (ConnectionError), entering retry loop.
```

I've tried to run the code with Google Colab, and it works.

I've tried to relogin but still get the same error,

I've tried to use different WLAN and even hotpot but get the same error.

I've tried to change to a different conda env with the same code but get the same error.

I've also tried to first run it offline and then syn the result but get the same error.

I've tried to use a Macbook and run the same code with the same command and IN THE SAME WLAN and it works!

As for the answer under wandb troubleshooting:

> Upgrade your SSL certificate. If you're running the script on an Ubuntu server, run update-ca-certificates We can't sync training logs without a valid SSL certificate because it's a security vulnerability.

I'm just using my personal computer and this is actually nothing to do with the SSL certificate right? Besiders that why could i access wandb perfectly while logging in but failed when trying to syn the result?

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

i've solved this problem with a stupid solution.

I uninstall the wandb with current version and install an older version
'pip install wandb==0.11.0'

If someone has a better solution please feel welcome to answer this question :)